# shell script acquire gateway address of eth0

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I would like to use a short shell script to get my default gateway address. so that it would do

```
$> whatismygateway.sh
192.168.100.10
```

I have tried `ifconfig eth0`, but it just does not contain any information about the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`route | grep default` should give you what you're looking for, although if you have multiple interfaces you may need to filter the results further.

Answer (score 1):

If `eth0` is your interface, you could try something like this

```
 cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0|grep GATEWAY|sed 's/^[A-Z].*=//'
```

output:

> 95.174.29.225

you can also use `route` command

Comment: This has a Useless Use of Cat and a Useless Use of Grep|Sed. It can be expressed as a single `sed` script, probably along the lines of `sed -n '/^GATEWAY=//p' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` but I'm not at my computer. This is likely specific to Ubuntu, and not portable to other distros.

Comment: @tripleee : you're probably right, but i just added `sed` after first grep and updated the code. However it works.